# Execute C# code on Centos (Linux)?

Tags: c#, linux, mono, centos, monodevelop

I have simple C# console application developed in Visual Studio 2008, which writes information in MySQL database. Is it possible to run the application in my hosting environment (Cent OS, with local MySQL database)? I have only control panel or ftp access to my hosting space. The database is only accessible from local (from the hosting space).

I have read something about Mono/Monodevelop, but those need to be run on the Cent OS, right? I don't have access to install this or other staffs on the hosting environment.

Comment: if you don't have root or administrator account, you cannot install Mono to compile an execute your aplicacion

Comment: @Jorge, that is not true, if you have a shell and the right compilers then you can build and run mono without admin rites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given what you've specified about the environment and your limitations, not you can't run it.

You will need to have Mono installed to run a .NET app on Linux.  If you can't install it, you're probably out of luck.

You could check with your hosting provider to see if they have other options.

Comment: Completly agreeing, just wanting to add, that a VPS is no longer much more expensive than shared hosting. Nothing stops you from creating a CentOS install with Mono in a VPS.

Comment: I debated even answering this, considering that this is really not the right place to ask this question.  This is specific to the hosting provider, and as such, I'm wondering if the question itself is off-topic.  It relates to programming, and a newer developer might find it helpful, but it is definitely borderline...  There's just no good, specific answer to this without knowing more about the hosting provider, and again, they're the people to ask in the first place.

Comment: Again completly agreeing: The same rationale made me comment on your answer instead of writing one myself.

Answer (score 2):

If your hosting provider allows it, has mono installed, and you've verified that your application runs under mono you may be able to invoke the program via a shell command from php.

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('mono myprogram.exe');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your host has mono installed, and you have the ability to execute arbitrary shell commands from PHP, then you can run it. Otherwise no. Do you have the source to the program? If so, I would just port the code to PHP (or whatever your host provides).

Comment: Yes, I have the source code, but I'm not very familiar with PHP. Is there any C# to PHP converter?

Comment: @LjupcoSofijanov Actually, yes! http://jsc.sourceforge.net/ Can't say whether it's any good or not, but I'd heard of such things before and found this on Google. And PHP is easy anyway. If you can manage to deal with C#, you should be able to pick up PHP no problem. EDIT: Apparently jsc deals with assemblies and not source, but you have that too. :)